# Unable to save Pandas DataFrame to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

The code I was using to save data scraped from my external module is no longer saving to `.csv`.

Initially, all the code was in a Jupyter notebook - now I've moved to two python files, importing the class/module.

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import pandas as pd
import MixcloudScraperDiscoverFunc as search


terms = ['house', 'trance', 'techno']
discover = search.MixCloudDiscover()
discover_data = discover.discover(terms)
now = datetime.now()
# print(mixcloud_data)
fields = ['Link', 'Curator', 'Followers', 'Bio', 'Location', 'Twitter']
currentDateTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S %p")
mixcloud_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(discover_data)
mixcloud_df.to_csv(
    f"Mixcloud_Data_{str(terms)}_{currentDateTime}.csv",
    index=False
)
```

Would anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: I get 3:

[26408:20696:0912/092506.067:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:25:06.068] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.   
-------
[26408:16664:0912/092550.939:ERROR:util.cc(129)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater

[6184:26904:0912/092650.977:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
-------
But I think these errors pre-existed my issues.

Comment: what you see when you print this `print(mixcloud_df)`?

Comment: maybe try a different explicit path?, r"C:\tmp\out.csv" looks like a permission problem, or trying to write to not existing folder

Comment: Yeah, try a different path, as @trigonom suggested.

Comment: @trigonom - Ok, I will try this. It turns out it's not saving to the same folder the python file is saved in. Thanks!!